# Change date format from MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS am/pm to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in a CSV file

Tags: linux, date, csv

I being trying to covert the date format for this csv file that I got from vendor so I can upload the data to my Google Bigquery. I am using a VM from Google Cloud Console.

The data look something like this:

```
Name ,Phone ,SalesDate ,Venue ,NoOfUnits ,ModifiedDatae

Victor ,5555555 ,12/6/2013 10:26:32 AM , Colosseum ,1 ,12/8/2013 1:05:45 PM
```

I am trying to make it in the format of:

```
Name ,Phone ,SalesDate ,Venue ,NoOfUnits ,ModifiedDatae

Victor ,5555555 ,2013-12-6 10:26:32 ,Colosseum,1 ,2013-12-8 13:05:45
```

I know I can use sed or awk.

Comment: Why do you have (seemingly) extraneous spaces in your data? Do you want to preserve white-space in your output data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Python script and a Bash script that should do what you want.

### Python Solution

Here's a Python script that converts all time-fields from one format to another, as specified in the question:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""reformat_time.py

Change date format from:

    MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS am/pm

to:

    YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

in a CSV file
"""

import csv
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import sys

# Open the file (taken as a command-line argument)
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:

    # Parse the CSV data
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    # Iterate over the rows
    for row in csvreader:

        # Iterate over the columns of each row
        for index, col in enumerate(row):

            # Try to parse and convert each column
            try:
                _datetime = datetime.strptime(col, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
                newcol = _datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

            # If parsing fails, leave the column unchanged
            except ValueError:
                newcol = col

            # Update the column value
            row[index] = newcol

        # Output the updated row
        print(','.join(row))
```

Suppose your CSV file is called `data.csv` and contains the following line (taken from your post):

```
Victor,5555555,12/6/2013 10:26:32 AM,Colosseum,1,12/8/2013 1:05:45 PM
```

Then you could run the script like this:

```bsh
python reformat_time.py data.csv
```

This would produce the following output:

```
Victor,5555555,2013-12-06 10:26:32,Colosseum,1,2013-12-08 01:05:45
```

### Bash Solution

And here is a Bash script using the GNU `date` utility which has (almost) the same effect:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# reformat_time.sh

# Loop over the lines of the file
while read -r line; do

    # Extract the field values for each row
    Name="$(echo ${line} | cut -d, -f1)";
    Phone="$(echo ${line} | cut -d, -f2)";
    SalesDate="$(echo ${line} | cut -d, -f3)";
    Venue="$(echo ${line} | cut -d, -f4)";
    NoOfUnits="$(echo ${line} | cut -d, -f5)";
    ModifiedDate="$(echo ${line} | cut -d, -f6)";

    # Convert the time-fields from the old format to the new format
    NewSalesDate="$(date -d "${SalesDate}" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")";
    NewModifiedDate="$(date -d "${ModifiedDate}" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")";

    # Output the updated row
    echo "${Name},${Phone},${NewSalesDate},${Venue},${NoOfUnits},${NewModifiedDate}";

done < "$1"
```

You could run it like this:

```bsh
bash reformat_time.sh data.csv
```

And it would produce the following output:

```
Victor ,5555555 ,2013-12-06 10:26:32, Colosseum ,1 ,2013-12-08 13:05:45
```

Notice that the Bash script is much more fragile. It does no error-handling and only affects the 3rd and 6th fields. It also preserves the white-space surrounding the field separator, which the above Python script does not.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! the Python code did the trick. Also thank you for all the explanations, it definitely help me better understand your querys

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to Linux and I being trying to covert the date format

Try utilizing `date` with the `-d` switch:

```
       -d, --date=STRING
              display time described by STRING, not 'now'
```

And then format the output the way you want it.

Example:

```
date -d "12/6/2013 10:26:32 AM" "+%F %H:%M:%S"
2013-12-06 10:26:32
```

For explanation of formatting, see `man date` (the `FORMAT` section).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this awk

```
awk -F, '
function cvtdate( dat,  array) {
    split(dat,array,"/| |:")
    array[4]=array[7]=="PM"?(array[4]+12):array[4]
    return array[3]"-"array[1]"-"array[2]" "array[4]":"array[5]":"array[6]
}
{
    $3=cvtdate($3)
    $6=cvtdate($6)
}1' OFS=',' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible awk oneliner:

```
awk -F, '{ a[3];a[6] ; for (i in a) "date -d \""$i"\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"" |& getline $i }1' OFS=, filename
```